# Uncaught ReferenceError: parseURL is not defined

Tags: javascript, referenceerror

I've defined a function named parseURL in javascript in the head of my file, and I have a button set so that when it is clicked, it should call said function. However, for some reason my debugger is telling me that parseURL is not defined. The exact error is "Uncaught ReferenceError: parseURL is not defined"

```
<HTML xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<HEAD>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css" type="text/css" />   
    <TITLE>
    Pic Grabber (javascript)
    </TITLE>
<script type="text/javascript" src="linkedURL.js" />

<script type="text/javascript">
var Page = {};
Page.currentURL = null;
Page.link = document.getElementById("link");

/*
###################################
# The function that "doesn't exist"
###################################
*/

function parseURL(){
    Page.url = document.getElementById("url").value;

    if(!checkValidURL(Page.url)){
        alert("Must Enter a valid URL");
    }

    Page.link.innerHTML = Page.url;

    return true;
}

function checkValidURL(url){
    var request = false;
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest;
    } 
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHttp");
    }
    else{
        alert("FAIL");
    }

    if (request) {
        request.open("GET", url);
        if (request.status == 200) { 
            return true; 
        }
    }

    return false;
}

</script>
</HEAD>
<BODY>
    <div class="wrap">
        <h1><a href="#">My Database</a></h1>
        <ul id="menu">
            <li><a href="../index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="../upload.php">Upload</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Advanced Search</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">My Profile</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="clear"></div>
        <div id="left">
            <a href="#" id="link"></a>
        </div>
        <div id="right">
            <div class="box">
                <form id="input">
                <p>URL:</p><br/>
                <input type="text" id="url" /><br />

                            #################################
                            # This is where the error appears
                            #################################

                <input type="button" id="getButton" value="Get Pics" onclick="parseURL()" />
                <input type="button" id="back" value="<< Back" onclick="back()" disabled="true"/>
                <input type="button" id="next" value="Next >>" onclick="next()" disabled="true"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</BODY>

</HTML>
```

It seems like it should be an easy fix, I've tried a bunch of things though and nothing seems to be working. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="linkedURL.js" />
```

to here:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="linkedURL.js"> </script>
</BODY>
```

Comment: That worked, the only other thing I had to do was change it from <script ... /> to <script ...></script>. Thanks for the fast response!

Comment: Oh yeah! I missed that. No problem

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have those hashes in your JavaScript? If so, they'll kill your script completely.

If you want to comment in JavaScript, you can use single line comments:

```
// This is a comment.
```

or multi-line comments:

```
/* This is
a comment */
```

Comment: Nah I just threw those in when posting the comment. Sorry, I can see that'd be confusing.

Comment: In that case, could you post your actual code, or at least a link to it, please? It'd help us help you

Answer (score 0):

I can see a few problems in that js, one of which may be causing the error :

1. You should not write , but always use . Some browsers are quite stupid.
2. You call document.getElementById("link") right at the beginning of the script. When that line executes, there is no element in the document having id link ... there is no element in the document at all. A naive solution is to move all the scripts at the end of the page, while the formally correct solution is to use the onload event.
3. Javascript does not support comments with #. It supports // for single lines, and /* .. */ for multiple lines.